# chartjs undefined length when using 2 datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to display the some dummy data as a test. I keep getting this error. Its caused in the actual Chart.js file..

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        labels: ["1", "2"],
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Test1",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    borderColor: "black",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "black",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "green",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "blue",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "black",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: [1,2,50,42,43,23,1],
                    spanGaps: false
                },
                {
                    label: "Test2",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "blue",
                    borderColor: "black",
                    borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                    borderDash: [],
                    borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                    borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                    pointBorderColor: "black",
                    pointBackgroundColor: "blue",
                    pointBorderWidth: 1,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "green",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "black",
                    pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                    pointRadius: 1,
                    pointHitRadius: 10,
                    data: [4,55,23,52,32,13,4],
                    spanGaps: false
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, I can't actually get this to work...

It looks fine to me,
any advice?

Comment: @MaxZoom edited to show it, I forgot to put it in!

Comment: Not sure where in code and when you are getting this error, as you have not mentioned it. But usually the error itself is saying that you are calling length property over null object, which I guess is "datasets" in this context.

Comment: @pranay editing now to show where it is

Comment: @MaxZoom that didn't fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your code and comparing with one that worked (taken from [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-chart-js-2-0-six-examples/) site) the problem became apparent.

First: your labels' property doesn't match - in length - with the data's. That might explain the length problem you mentioned.

Second, you have to move the labels property into the data object.

```
data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
    ...
```

Check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/pCQWH5MyVbQtPjHWgzIg?p=preview) working example based on your code.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need the X-axis labels in your main data:

```
    data: {
       labels : ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
       datasets: [
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/40L55fsr/)